# How to implement video upload functionality

Tags: iphone

I am working on one app in which i need to upload video and audio, i had heard lot about mediapicker but i am not getting actually how to deal with it.
Can anyone please tell me about this.

Comment: I have done upload video but problem is accuring when i try to upload audio because we can't access file system of iphone its only work in iphone 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.example.com/uploadvideoxml.php?user_id=%@",[vedioDict valueForKey:@"user_id"]];

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];

NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];

[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@.mov\"\r\n",valuestr]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:[vedioDict valueForKey:@"VideoUrl"]]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:returnData]; 

[xmlParser setDelegate:self];

[xmlParser parse];
```

Comment: I had also done this same thing to upload image data to server but i am stucking when i want to choose any specific video or audio file from my iphone library.I had also tried image picker with media info for that but no result..do you have any solution for this???

Comment: Image_picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
 Image_picker.delegate = self;
 Image_picker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
 Image_picker.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController  availableMediaTypesForSourceType:videoPickerCtrl.sourceType];   

 Image_picker.allowsImageEditing = NO;
 Image_picker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];
I am getting error on -- kUTTypeMovie

Comment: have you import file #import <MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h> and framewrok mobilecoreservices in your project

Comment: Hi, I am trying with new wddc code of avcamdemo but in that problem is that i am not able to save video in local cache and my phone will not support asset library.

Comment: only ios 4.0 have asset library ,you want to save video of cam in you phone ??

Comment: have you do work on audio file to save , me got problem in save audio file

Comment: it is just a code to show video in imagepicker not to savevedio if you using 3g iphone then it will not work , ok i show you the code to show video of photo library

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi,
```

By using this code you can send any audio file to server...follow this simple steps..
This steps are also applicable when you want to send image to server

```
NSString *postData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your XML goes here";
```

titleForSegmentAtIndex:self.participantSegmentCtrl.selectedSegmentIndex],ratingStar,[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", adviceTypeSegmentCtrl.selectedSegmentIndex],USER_CREDENTIALS];
NSLog(@"local audio upload ... %@",postData);
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];

NSString *urlString = [SERVER_IP stringByAppendingString:@"getAudioadvise_ipad.php"];
NSData *audioData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:fileName];
//if ([audioData length]<=0)
// return;

request= [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";

NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];

[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *postbody = [NSMutableData data];

//parameter1
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"postData\"\r\n\r\n%@", postData] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
//Tags

[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@.wav\"\r\n", [schedule_Obj.ID objectAtIndex:[schedule_Obj.recordIndex intValue]]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:audioData]];//add audio data here
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:postbody];
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[audioData release];

Comment: This is not correct way to send audio file to server , have you able to save song of iphone in NSData,

Comment: are need code to send video to server then i can send you that full code ,

Comment: yes, i need to send full recorded video to server..if u have code please send it to me on sparshme5@gmail.com